# What happens when we store a non-integer in int array?

Tags: c

If I store a character in an int array, I'll see the character's ASCII value, but if I store any other non-integer, things don't seem to work.

```
int a[3]={1,2,'-'};
printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
```

Here, I don't get any output from the compiler.

What is happening here?

Comment: There is no non-integer! A _character-constant_ **is** an `int`.

Comment: It converts it to an `int`

Comment: `printf` gives you output from the execution of your program.

Comment: Your snippet should work just fine: https://ideone.com/VlbkrR

Comment: @EdHeal: Nope. no need to convert.

Comment: @Olaf No need to, it is implicit. That is what Ed is saying.

Comment: @olaf - Really - conceptually we convert it from a char to an int. Also the compiler converts it as well

Comment: What output are you expecting from the compiler?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: There **is no conversion**, because a _character-constant_ already has type `int`. And an explicit conversion would be a cast.

Comment: @EdHeal Character literals are of type char only in C++. In C, they're  ints already.

Comment: @EdHeal: If there was a conversion, I had not commented, it **is** an `int`.

Comment: I didn't see any output when I ran this code here- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php which is why I asked the question.

I guess the question should be closed if you do see the output, though I'm surprised that the online compiler above doesn't show any output.

Comment: There is no problem with that code. If you have a problem with **other** code, why post the correct one?

Comment: I had no trouble pasting your code into the provided main function at the site you linked and getting the expected output when I pressed execute.  Perhaps you only pressed compile and not execute?  The site doesn't seem to work when you try to share the code though. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Character literals in C have type `int`. Thus all initializers in this declaration

```
int a[3]={1,2,'-'};
```

have type int.

Moreover there is so-called the integer promotion in C that promotes objects of all integer types with the rank less than the rank of the type int to the type int.

Comment: So `char c = 'a'` is a narrowing conversion?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: If you enable conversion warnings, you indeed get a warning. That's actually one of the recommended warnings.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe  In fact there is no narrowing conversion because the integer literal 'a' can be stored in the type char. If you used a variable instead of the literal then the compiler could issue a diagnostic message.